# Why malloc(1) gives more than one page size?

Tags: c, malloc, sbrk

I have tried in my machine using sbrk(1) and then deliberately write out of bound to test page size, which is 4096 bytes. But when I call malloc(1), I get SEGV after accessing 135152 bytes, which is way more than one page size. I know that malloc is library function and it is implementation dependent, but considering that it calls sbrk eventually, why will it give more than one page size. Can anyone tell me about its internal working?

My operating system is ubuntu 14.04 and my architecture is x86

Update: Now I am wondering if it's because malloc returns the address to a free list block that is large enough to hold my data. But that address may be in the middle of the heap so that I can keep writing until the upper limit of the heap is reached.

Comment: What operating system and architecture are you using exactly?
Also, are you sure that malloc() calls sbrk()?

Comment: I am not sure, but my professor and some online sources tell me that. I am using x86 architecture under ubuntu 14.04

Comment: ITYM 4096, not 4086. What's with the "(1)"s? `sbrk` is a system call (2) and `malloc` is a library function (3).

Comment: Well, I can't do more than speculate about your particular malloc(), but I've often seen people assume "x library function calls y under the hood" when that isn't necessarily true (like, maybe x() called y() ten years ago, but things changed since).
Also, have you tried breakpointing in malloc() and then stepping through it to see what it calls?

Comment: The question should include what OS and hardware you are using

Comment: I think the reason is exactly what you wrote under "Update:"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Older `malloc()` implementations of UNIX used `sbrk()`/`brk()` system calls. But these days, implementations use `mmap()` and `sbrk()`.  The `malloc()` implementation of glibc (that's probably the one you use on your Ubuntu 14.04) uses both [`sbrk()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) and [`mmap()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and the choice to use which one to allocate when you request the typically depends on the size of the allocation request, which glibc does dynamically.

For small allocations, glibc uses `sbrk()` and for larger allocations it uses `mmap()`. The macro [`M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=35c8863a32110a515d863c24464baa96467fc2f0;hb=a62719ba90e2fa1728890ae7dc8df9e32a622e7b#l1013) is used to decide this. Currently, it's default value is [set to 128K](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=35c8863a32110a515d863c24464baa96467fc2f0;hb=a62719ba90e2fa1728890ae7dc8df9e32a622e7b#l635). This explains why your code managed to allocate 135152 bytes as it is roughly ~128K. Even though, you requested only 1 byte, your implementation allocates 128K for efficient memory allocation. So segfault didn't occur until you cross this limit.

You can play with `M_MAP_THRESHOLD` by using [`mallopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) by changing the default parameters.

> M_MMAP_THRESHOLD
>
> For allocations greater than or equal to the limit
>   specified (in bytes) by M_MMAP_THRESHOLD that can't be satisfied  from
>   the free list, the memory-allocation functions employ mmap(2) instead
>   of increasing the program break using sbrk(2).
>
> Allocating  memory  using  mmap(2)  has the significant advantage that
>   the allocated memory blocks can always be independently released back
>   to the system.  (By contrast, the heap can be trimmed only if memory
>   is freed at the top  end.)   On  the  other hand,  there are some
>   disadvantages to the use of mmap(2): deallocated space is not placed
>   on the free list for reuse by later allocations; memory may be wasted
>   because mmap(2) allocations must be page-aligned; and the kernel must
>   perform the  expensive task  of  zeroing  out  memory  allocated via
>   mmap(2).  Balancing these factors leads to a default setting of
>   128*1024 for the M_MMAP_THRESHOLD parameter.
>
> The lower limit for this parameter is 0.  The upper  limit  is 
>   DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX:  512*1024  on  32-bit  systems  or
>   4*1024*1024*sizeof(long) on 64-bit systems.
>
> Note:  Nowadays,  glibc  uses  a  dynamic mmap threshold by default. 
>   The initial value of the threshold is 128*1024, but when  blocks
>   larger than the current threshold and less than or equal to
>   DEFAULT_MMAP_THRESHOLD_MAX  are  freed,  the  threshold  is adjusted 
>   upward  to the size of the freed block.  When dynamic mmap
>   thresholding is in effect, the threshold for trimming the heap is also
>   dynamically adjusted to be twice the dynamic mmap threshold.  Dynamic
>   adjustment of the mmap  threshold  is  disabled if any of the
>   M_TRIM_THRESHOLD, M_TOP_PAD, M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, or M_MMAP_MAX
>   parameters is set.

For example, if you do:

```
#include<malloc.h>

mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, 0);
```

before calling `malloc()`, you'll likely see a different limit. Most of these are implementation details and C standard says it's [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to write into memory that your process doesn't own. So do it at your risk -- otherwise, [demons may fly out of your nose](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1857) ;-)

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps

Answer (score 4):

`malloc` allocates memory in large blocks for performance reasons. Subsequent calls to `malloc` can give you memory from the large block instead of having to ask the operating system for a lot of small blocks. This cuts down on the number of system calls needed.

From [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6390):

> When a process needs memory, some room is created by moving the upper bound of the heap forward, using the brk() or sbrk() system calls. Because a system call is expensive in terms of CPU usage, a better strategy is to call brk() to grab a large chunk of memory and then split it as needed to get smaller chunks. This is exactly what malloc() does. It aggregates a lot of smaller malloc() requests into fewer large brk() calls. Doing so yields a significant performance improvement.

Note that some modern implementations of `malloc` use `mmap` instead of `brk`/`sbrk` to allocate memory, but otherwise the above is still true.